# What is the best structure for updating the keywords of emails?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have to read in emails for a particular user. At the moment I'm reading in the email removing all the noise words and just getting keywords and writing these keywords to a textfile user001.txt . The more emails I read the larger the textfile gets. Then I read the user001.txt and get the top 10 most used words for that user.

Because the files could get very big I was thinking the I would write to a file the word and the occurrence `{apple}{3}`. Then for the subsequent emails I would have to read the user001.txt and for example if the word apple appears 5 times in a subsequent email I would have to increase apple in the text file by 5 so it would now read `{apple}{8}`. What is the best structure for the this particular problem ?

What is the best approach to this problem as a whole ?

Comment: @LutzHorn I have to use textfiles.

Comment: Then just append to the files and use shell tools like `grep`, `sed`, `uniq`, and `wc` to analyze the data.

Comment: @LutzHorn, this is most likely an assignment if he _has_ to use text files. which means only java.

Comment: how about, serializing a `Map<String, Integer>` to file? this will keep the words unique, while keeping count

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html !

Answer (score 0):

just because you analyze the mails and write out `apple 3` in the mail, it doesn't mean that you need to update it, you can add in the subsequent lines `apple 5` and `apple 2` and once in a while (could be a cron job) you can go through the file and merge them to `apple 10`

This technique is used by several NoSQL databases as well. Because it's easier and faster to append information and storage usually is pretty cheap. And afterwards that operation to optimize the storage and remove unused data can be run whenever the database, computer, server, ... is under a low load and it doesn't affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best approach - or even a good one, but i'd say a good "datastructure" that could be read through relatively quickly would be a simple list. The File would look something like this:

```
apple: 3
chrome: 4
explorer: 0
```

This file can then be read line by line using e.g. a `BufferedReader`. Each line will have one keyword and the corresponding value.

to check if a line matches the keyword you would use

```java
String key = "apple" // your key here
String line = ...    // the line to check here
boolean matches = line.startsWith(key + ":");
int currentValue = Integer.parseInt(line.split(":")[1].trim());
```

Once you have found the matching line, you can read its value with the code above, add the new count to it and store it back to the file.
Concerning the topic of efficient editing / reading of large files I am sure you will find a lot of material via Google.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that you can probably have to maintain a data file in a particular format. 
For eg Apple,5 ...
So each time you start your application, you can just load the entire data in the file into a Map. Then you can update the count of existing strings in the Map and even add other strings as well to the Map. Then you just write the content into the Data file.